# qmake: how to build dependencies without TEMPLATE=subdirs

Tags: qt, dependencies, qmake

TL;DR: Is there a way to build a target from a .pro file in a different project without using TEMPLATE = subdirs?

Long version:

I have a complex project (`mycomplexproject`) with lots of subirs and *.pro files. One module (`moduleA`) depends on a DLL built in a different project outside of this project (`anotherproject`). Because reasons I cannot create a *.pro file with a subdirs template in `somerootdir`.
Is there a way to add a dependency in `moduleA.pro` so `anotherproject` is built whenever `moduleA` is built and `anotherproject.dll` does not exist without having to create a *.pro file in `somerootdir`?

```
somerootdir/
    anotherproject/                // must be independent of mycomplexproject
        anotherproject.pro
        lib/
            anotherproject.dll     // the result of building anotherproject
    [...]      
    mycomplexproject/
        core/
            core.pro
        modules/
            moduleA/
                moduleA.pro        // depends on anotherproject.dll built from anotherproject.pro
            moduleB/
                moduleB.pro     
            modules.pro            // uses subdir template
        mycomplexproject.pro       // uses subdir template
```

P.S.: `moduleA` is only built under certain circumstances, and building `anotherproject` is only necessary if `moduleA`is built.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Not really, there doesn't seem to be a solution with qmake. IIRC we restructured the project and used custom build batch scripts to achive something similar.